# How can I update domain information on an SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

When creating the SSL cert (LetsEncrypt) I forgot to include the www variant of my domain.

How can I go about adding it in? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: An SSL *certificate*. There is no such thing as 'an SSL'.

Comment: Add the domain and renew the cert, it's that simple :D

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing preventing you from creating a new one. So just create a new one and use that.

Your operating system is irrelevant.

Comment: "To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain contain(s) the right IP address." I'm thrown this error when I try to create the certificate with the www.mydomain.com added (mydomain.com doesn't give this error though).

Comment: Now you're going to have to show the commands you used in your question along with this error.